# How to set state from Multiple API call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having this issue with setState in the code.

**Trying to do**

what I wanted to achieve is to concatenate results from all the API calls into one variable in State.Should I assign everything in the first API (as in second or third API call wrap within the first API .then(function) ?)
or 
should i define each api separately

```
var requestDigAPI = ...
var requestNEWSAPI =...
```

and call

```
    this.setstate({
   this.state.articles.concat(dig,buzzfeed)
})
```

What is the right approach?

**ERRORs**

No matter the method react logs error. 
If I set the State in other API within the first API returns

> error  buzzfeed unidentified

or setState outside of both API

> error dig , buzzfeed unidentified

```js
    componentDidMount() {
    
        this.setState({loading: true})
    
        var apiRequestDig = fetch("api").then(function(response) {
    
          return response.json()
    
        });
    
        var apiRequestNews = fetch("api").then(function(response) {
    
          return response.json()
    
        })
    
        var apiREquestBuzzFeed = fetch(api).then(function(response) {
    
          return response.json()
    
        })
    
        var combinedData = {
          "apiRequestDig": {},
          "apiRequestNews": {},
          "apiREquestBuzzFeed": {}
        };
    
        Promise.all([apiRequestDig, apiRequestNews, apiREquestBuzzFeed]).then(function(values) {
          combinedData["apiRequestDig"] = values[0];
          combinedData["apiRequestNews"] = values[1];
          combinedData["apiREquestBuzzFeed"] = values[2];
    
    
    
          return combinedData;
        });
    
    
       var dig = apiRequestDig.then(results => {
          let dig = results.data.feed.map(article => {
    
            return {
              title: article.content.title_alt,
              image: article.content.media.images[0].url,
              category: article.content.tags[0].name,
              count: article.digg_score,
              description: article.content.description,
              url: article.content.url
            }
    
          })
          apiREquestBuzzFeed.then(results => {
             console.log(results.big_stories[0].title)
    
             let buzzfeed = results.big_stories.map(article => {
               return {
                 title: article.title,
                 image: article.images.small,
                 category: article.category,
                 count: article.impressions,
                 description: article.description,
                 url: "https://www.buzzfeed.com"+article.canonical_path
               }
             })
           })
    
               this.setState({
                 articles: this.state.articles.concat(dig),
                  loading: "none"
                })
    
    
    
          // console.log(this.state);
        })
    
    
    
      }
```

thanks for the advice

Answer (score 2):

How about moving state manipulation code within the `resolve` callback of `Promise.all` ?

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({loading: true})
    const apiRequestDig = fetch("api").then(response => response.json());
    const apiRequestNews = fetch("api").then(response => response.json());
    const apiREquestBuzzFeed = fetch("api").then(response => response.json());

    Promise.all([
      apiRequestDig, 
      apiRequestNews, 
      apiREquestBuzzFeed
    ]).then(([dig, news, feed]) => {
      const digs = dig.data.feed.map(article => ({
        title: article.content.title_alt,
        image: article.content.media.images[0].url,
        category: article.content.tags[0].name,
        count: article.digg_score,
        description: article.content.description,
        url: article.content.url
      }));
      const buzzfeed = feed.big_stories.map(article => ({
        title: article.title,
        image: article.images.small,
        category: article.category,
        count: article.impressions,
        description: article.description,
        url: `https://www.buzzfeed.com${article.canonical_path}`
      }));
      this.setState({
        articles: [...this.state.articles, ...digs],
        loading: "none"
      });
      // return anything you want as wrapped with promise
      return {
        apiRequestDig: dig,
        apiRequestNews: news,
        apiREquestBuzzFeed: feed
      };
    });
    .catch(e => {
      // catch your error here
    })
}
```

Comment: how do i concatenate other array ? using "..." ?

Comment: yes, you can use es6 [spread](https://gist.github.com/yesvods/51af798dd1e7058625f4) syntax to concatenate other array

Comment: i tried the code by it only works if i call the setState 3 time to each api , need to find a way to DRY my code

Answer (score 2):

You *could* chain your API calls, but `Promise.all()` allows you to make concurrent calls, so why not use it?

However, I think your API functions should be defined outside of `componentDidMount`, for more readability and reusability:

```
/* Outside of your component */
const apiRequest = url => fetch(url).then(response => response.json())

const apiRequestDig = () => {
    return apiRequest("https://dig/api/url").then(results => {
        return results.data.feed.map(article => {
            return {
                title: article.content.title_alt
                /* ... */
            };
        });
    });
};

const apiRequestNews = () => {
    return apiRequest("https://news/api/url").then(results => {
        return results.big_stories.map(article => {
            return {
                title: article.title
                /* ... */
            };
        });
    });
};

const apiRequestBuzzFeed = () => {
    return apiRequest("https://buzzfeed/api/url").then(results => {
        return results.big_stories.map(article => {
            return {
                title: article.title
                /* ... */
            };
        });
    });
};

/* Inside your component */
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({loading: true});

    Promise.all([
        apiRequestDig(),
        apiRequestNews(),
        apiRequestBuzzFeed()
    ]).then(values => {
        return values[0].concat(values[1], values[2]);
    }).then(results => {
        this.setState({
            articles: this.state.articles.concat(results),
            loading: "none"
        });
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('Oops, something went wrong', err);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Promise.all will be the best approach.But keep in mind about the fail fast behavior of Promise.all where in if one request fails then Promise.all will reject immediately [MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). This behavior can be mitigated by catching the error and resolving with empty data.

```js
function makeAPICall(postId) {
    return fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${postId}`).then(res => res.json());
}

var Posts = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {};
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        var requestsArray = [makeAPICall(1), makeAPICall(2), makeAPICall(3)];
        Promise.all(requestsArray).then(values => {
            var postTitles = values.map(post => post.title).join(",   ");
            this.setState({
                data: postTitles
            });
        }).catch(console.error.bind(console));
    },
    render: function() {
        return <div>{this.state.data}</div>;
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <Posts/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```